# How to get videos with PHVideo from iCloud on Xamarin iOS?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, icloud, multimedia, phimagemanager

I implemented multimedia picker (for images and videos) with DependencyService on Xamarin.Forms app. I have a problem on iCloud videos.
When I select video that is on icloud, I can't get it.

My implementation is:

```
async void FinishedPickingAssets(object sender, MultiAssetEventArgs args)
         {
             IList<MediaFile> results = new List<MediaFile>();
             TaskCompletionSource<IList<MediaFile>> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IList<MediaFile>>();
    
             try 
             { 
                 var options = new PHImageRequestOptions()
                 {
                     NetworkAccessAllowed = true
                 };
    
                 options.Synchronous = false;
                 options.ResizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeMode.Fast;
                 options.DeliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode.HighQualityFormat;
                 bool completed = false;
                 for (var i = 0; i < args.Assets.Length; i++)
                 {
                     var asset = args.Assets[i];
    
                     string fileName = string.Empty;
                     if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(9, 0))
                     {
                         fileName = PHAssetResource.GetAssetResources(asset).FirstOrDefault().OriginalFilename;
                         fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName) + "(" + i.ToString() + ")" + Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                     }
    
                     switch (asset.MediaType)
                     {
                         case PHAssetMediaType.Video:
                         {
                                 var vOptions = new PHVideoRequestOptions();
                                 vOptions.NetworkAccessAllowed = true;
                                 vOptions.Version = PHVideoRequestOptionsVersion.Original;
                                 vOptions.DeliveryMode = PHVideoRequestOptionsDeliveryMode.Automatic;
                                 string videoUrl = "";
    
                                 PHImageManager.DefaultManager.RequestAvAsset(asset, vOptions, (avAsset, audioMix, vInfo) => 
                                 {
                                     DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync(() => {
    
                                         var error = vInfo.ObjectForKey(PHImageKeys.Error);
                                            
                                         if (avAsset != null)
                                         {
                                             videoUrl = ((AVFoundation.AVUrlAsset)avAsset).Url.Path;
                                         }
                                         var meFile = new MediaFile()
                                         {
                                             FileName = fileName,
                                             FilePath = videoUrl
                                         };
    
                                         using (Stream source = File.OpenRead(videoUrl))
                                         {
                                             meFile.FileSize = source.Length;
                                         }
                                         results.Add(meFile);
                                         OnMediaPicked?.Invoke(this, meFile);
    
                                         if (args.Assets.Length == results.Count && !completed)
                                         {
                                             completed = true;
                                             tcs.TrySetResult(results);
                                         }
                                     });
                                 });
                         }
                         break;
                     default:
                         PHImageManager.DefaultManager.RequestImageData(asset, options, (data, dataUti, orientation, info) =>
                         {
    
                             string path = FileHelper.GetOutputPath(MediaFileType.Image, TemporalDirectoryName, fileName);
    
                             if (!File.Exists(path))
                             {
                                 Debug.WriteLine(dataUti);
                                 var imageData = data;
                                 imageData?.Save(path, true);
                             }
    
                             var meFile = new MediaFile()
                             {
                                 FileName = fileName,
                                 FilePath = path,
                                 FileSize = File.ReadAllBytes(path).Length
                             };
    
                             results.Add(meFile);
                             OnMediaPicked?.Invoke(this, meFile);
                             if (args.Assets.Length == results.Count && !completed)
                             {
                                 completed = true;
                                 tcs.TrySetResult(results);
                             }
    
                         });
                         break;
                     }
                 }
             }
             catch
             {
                 tcs.TrySetResult(results);
    
                 string automationId = "UnexpectedSituationMessage";
                 GeneralOperations.OpenToastMessage("Unexpected Situation", automationId);
             }
    
             mediaPickTcs?.TrySetResult(await tcs.Task);
         }
```

When I try to select iCloud object, I get following error:
[image]

How can I take videos with multiple select from icloud?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The 1005 error means you're denied access. There can be multiple reasons for this. 1. Website Administrator has blocked a whole range of IP Addresses.
2. The VPN Service that you are using is blocked by the website.
3. Cloudflare or other similar service has blocked your IP Address for violation of their terms or any suspicious behavior. Try to use VPN or Proxy server to change your IP address or uninstall/disable your VPN service. And try again.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But I am not sure cause of my problem is this. Because in first try i get error but pulling the video to phone is started. after pull the video to phone, I can get it second time. Additionally I can pull manuelly with same ip address.

Comment: Do you have the entitlements set correctly? And do you have the entitlements set in the build settings?

Comment: Yes, I set  entitlements correctly. Actually I found a solution. When there is no enough memory in phone, video is stored in iCloud (only video thumbnail are shown). My problem is when I try to select the video with picker, it couldn't find the video because video is in icloud.
If I cannot access the file because of the file is in iCloud, I found that I could catch the error with the code as following:
var error = vInfo.ObjectForKey(PHImageKeys.Error);
And if error is not null, I showed a message (as file is in icloud, firstly you must download it to phone) to client.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure that you had turn on iCloud Photos .

```
 1. Go to Settings > [your name] > iCloud.
 2. Tap Photos.
 3. If you need to, tap to turn on iCloud Photos.
```

[image]

Then check if the video and photo display in Photo App on your device .

For  multiple selection and several customizations you could install the plugin [GMImagePicker.Xamarin](https://github.com/roycornelissen/GMImagePicker.Xamarin) from nuget .

Comment: Hi, I already use GMImagePicker. My shared code snippet is its FinishedPickingAssets method. Like following:
```var picker = new GMImagePickerController ();
picker.FinishedPickingAssets += FinishedPickingAssets;
await PresentViewControllerAsync (picker, true);```
I am having trouble getting the path and size information of the video in iCloud with GMImagePicker.And I checked iCloud Photos is turn on. But i realized that I am having trouble first time when i get the item. First time i get the error but pulling video is starting.

Comment: When I wait after getting error, video pulled from iCloud. That's why second time i can get it. But I want to wait first time until pull video to phone.

Comment: Could you share the sample to github so that I can test it on my side ?

Comment: It is a part of a big custom project. That's why I can't share now. But I will try to do demo project. I will share. Thank you.

Comment: OK ,I will check it asap after you upload it .